# How to get around gem dependency?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I've been trying to add the `make_flaggable` gem to my Rails project and have been getting the following error.

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activerecord":
  In Gemfile:
    make_flaggable (>= 0) ruby depends on
      activerecord (< 4.2, >= 3.0) ruby

    rails (= 4.2.1) ruby depends on
      activerecord (4.2.1)
```

I've tried `bundle update` and installing the gems in differing order, but neither of these get around the real issue.

Is the best way to get around this to fork the Gem and make my own copy without the < 4.2 dependency? Or is there another way to install `make_flaggable` without moving to an older version of Rails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meanwhile, I've found a fork maintained by `dgilperez` that supports Rails 4.2.

https://github.com/dgilperez/make_flaggable.

Both of these gems, however, I have been unable to install successfully and seem unmaintained.